# Selenium with Tor / Marionette is not working

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, webdriver, tor

I've got a big problem with my selenium 3.0, when I try to use it with Tor Project. I have launched the Tor Browser with Selenium, but if I try to choose an option from an select Element, it simply doesn't work. I think Marionette isn't working with Tor, did someone managed to run it?

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "/Users/alixmuselmann/Documents/**/**/**/**/geckodriver");

        String torPath = "/Users/alixmuselmann/Downloads/TorBrowser.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox";
        String profilePath = "/Users/alixmuselmann/Library/Application Support/TorBrowser-Data/Browser/nsqp6dzx.default";

        File torProfileDir = new File(profilePath);
        FirefoxBinary binary = new FirefoxBinary(new File(torPath));
        FirefoxProfile torProfile = new FirefoxProfile(torProfileDir);
        FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

Comment: Better bet is to use Firefox browser and configure it to use Tor's SOCKS proxy rather than Tor browser.  Tor browser is several versions behind the current Firefox release so you might need to use an older gecko or Selenium driver as some fundamental changes have taken place between these versions.

Comment: Ah, exactly what I thought. The problem is, that I have to test some antibot software on the server and for this purpose I need a highly anonymous browser.

Comment: That makes sense.  I forget the exact version but I think maybe Firefox 49 (or 47?) stopped working with Selenium 2.53 so you might have better luck with Tor browser and Selenium Server Standalone <= 2.48 (not Geckodriver).  Right now Tor browser is using Firefox 45.